# Problema con lector de códigos de barra en VueJS

Tags: vuejs, scanner

En el siguiente código tengo un campo de entrada en el cual cada vez que se pistolea un código se va a llamar al metodo que aparece abajo. El problema es que cada vez que pistoleo algo aparece un código distinto (el mismo pero incompleto). Aveces le faltan letras entremedio o al final.

```js
validateChip() {
   console.log(this.lccid);          
},
```

```html
<md-field>
    <label><md-icon>search</md-icon></label>
    <md-input type="text" v-model="lccid" v-on:keypress.enter="validateChip($event)"></md-input>
</md-field>
```

[image: ejemplo escaneando el mismo código de barra]

Comment: PD: probe escaneando dentro de Excel, y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: ¿El lector de código de barras es nuevo? Es probable que se encuentre averiado

Comment: @fredyfx no amigo, probe escaneando el mismo código pero dentro de una casilla de excel repetidas veces y siempre mostro el mismo valor. Pero en mi página siempre varia, no sé si será que el input no alcanza a capturar cada uno de los caracteres que se ingresan al escanear.

Comment: hace años trabajé con lectores de código de barra. Uno dañado fue la falla. Básicamente lo que hace un lector es "traducir barras a números y darle un enter". Usa un block de notas para verificar

Comment: @fredyfx Lo acabo de hacer y funciona de maravilla. Voy a intentar cambiar el input de vuematerial por uno normal, para descartar.

Comment: Dale, porque hasta el momento, no percibo que sea por vuejs

Comment: @fredyfx perdón la tardanza, te respondo para cerrar el tema. Al final era problema del lector, probé con otro modelo y funciono